# jQuery $.get() function succeeds with 200 but returns no content in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I'm writing my first bit of jQuery, and I'm having a problem with `jQuery.get()`. I'm calling this;

```
$.get(url, updateList);
```

where updateList is defined like so;

```
function updateList(data)
{
    if (data)
    {
        $('#contentlist').html(data);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#contentlist').html('<li><a href="#" id="synclink">Nothing found. Try again</a></li>');
    }
}
```

The function runs, and `updateList` is called. It works fine in Internet Explorer. However, in Firefox, the `data` parameter is always empty. I would expect it to be filled with the content of the webpage I passed in as the URL. Am I using it wrong?

Notes;

- in Firebug, I've enabled the *Net* panel, and I get the request showing up. I get a `200 OK`. The `Headers` tab looks fine, while the `Response` and `HTML` panels are both empty.
- The page I'm trying to download is a straight HTML page -- there's no problem with server code.
- The page with JavaScript is local to my machine; the page I'm downloading is hosted on the Internet.
- I've tried checking the URL by copy-pasting it from my page into the browser -- it happily returns content.
- The error occurs even in Firefox Safe Mode -- hopefully that rules out rogue addins.

Comment: have you stepped through the server code to ensure that it returns any data?

Comment: Completely unrelated, but I have to tell it: Yesterday, I was at a horse race for the first time in my life. I just *had* to bet on the horse called "Ajax". It came in fourth, so I lost my 2 Euros. Please continue, nothing to see here.

Comment: Just noticed it works fine in IE. There is no code on the server -- it's a straight html page.

Comment: have you tried copy-pasting the URL into a separate tab to ensure that the url variable is correct?

Comment: "have you tried copy-pasting the URL": I have - it works.

Comment: Post the HTML that the server returns.

Comment: The server returns this;

    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>

IE correctly updates the UL I'm trying for, but firefox does not. If I write

  alert(data);

in the javascript, Firefox prompts me with

    >><<

but IE shows

    >><li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li><<

Comment: A simple test works for me in Firefox: http://jsbin.com/uwaze  something in your headers maybe?  content-length=0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably won't be able to do this due to cross-domain security. Internet Explorer will allow you to Ajax remote domain when running from `file://`, but Firefox and Chrome won't.

Try to put both files on the same server and see if it works (it should).

Comment: Yeah. Once I moved from file protocol to http, it started to work. I just created a local site in IIS and accessed it as http://localhost/... and voila!

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely need to fix your page that you're quering with XHR because it should be returning content. Copy paste the link in the Firebug net tab and make a new tab, and edit that page with your text editor so it spits content back.

Comment: The page I'm querying is a simple html fragment in a .html file. Browsing to it shows the content. Should I do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Stick alert (or breakpoint in Firebug) and see if the data returned is not an object (or if there is any data). If the former - you may need to drill into the object to get your markup

Comment: The data returned is empty; there is no object.

Comment: To the point that people already made - do you have your HTML you are querying on a different URL? If you have it on totally different domain you won't be able to bypass restrictions (unless you implement a proxy as shown here http://is.gd/1P5iw) if you have subdomain there's way of achiving it (see http://is.gd/1P5oz) 
Now - if you do $.ajax instead of $.get you can also have "onerror" callback - have you try that?