# Jquery - $.get return empty value with a 200 status

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to get some data on this site http://www.amf.asso.fr/, especially on this type of page http://www.amf.asso.fr/annuaire/index.asp?refer=commune&dep_n_id=45&NUM_INSEE=45001. For this purpose i'm using this code :

```
$.get('myproxy.php?url=http://www.amf.asso.fr/annuaire/index.asp?refer=commune&dep_n_id=45&NUM_INSEE=45001', function (a) {
// do something
});
```

and here my proxy file :

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
if (isset($_GET['url']) && preg_match('`^http://`', $_GET['url'])) {
echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
}
?>
```

I get a response with 200 status

```
Request URL: myproxy.php?url=http://www.amf.asso.fr/annuaire/index.asp?refer=commune&dep_n_id=45&NUM_INSEE=45001
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

but no content at all. I'm not an expert so i don't see why because it work perfectly several time on other site. Is there something on the page that prevent me to get the content ? What i'm missing ? Thank for your help/insights.

Comment: most likely said remote site is returning no content at all when accessed that way.

Comment: It do, with the base url for exemple. But i think your right for the page i'm looking for. Do you know if there is a way around ?

Comment: you could set specific headers that would cause your request to mimic a browser request, but it all depends on what that server is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't be able to do this due to cross-domain security on the amf.asso.fr site.

As described on this article: [jQuery $.get() function succeeds with 200 but returns no content in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188976/jquery-get-function-succeeds-with-200-but-returns-no-content-in-firefox?rq=1)

Try using cURL instead:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$_GET['url']);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

echo $query;
```

Comment: Thank, indeed i should i've add that the code work on the remote site. And if i use your php, i get a error 500 for this site, same for the site on wich the code was previsouly working.

Comment: I dont think cors has anything to do with this, he isn't making a cross-origin request with javascript.

Comment: What happens if you do something simple like <?php echo 'test'; ?> to your PHP site? don't set the header or anything complex. Can you load that page in your browser and get a 200 OK?

Comment: Yes, and again this php code has work without a problem in the past with domain that don't allow cross-domain request.

Comment: I've edited the answer to suggest you try cURL instead. That website is refusing the `file_get_contents`, however cURL is returning an unstyled version. You'd need to do some cleanup if you're parsing for relative-referenced items.

Comment: Thank @r3mus i'm trying the curl solution for now (i've to read some material first, i'm not familiar with curl)

Comment: Depending on your server you might not have it installed either - some php configurations don't include it by default. Here's a good Ubuntu step-by-step: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9293/how-do-i-install-curl-in-php5

Comment: I had it install, i was just reading some stuff to actually know what i'm doing before doing it ;) So it work, but (there's always one -_-) i can't get the query url to pass along now. So i get my page with an error because there's no query. Noneless thank for your help ! I'll try to fix the remain problems.

Comment: yw! Glad you're making progress.